# i have a turned off computer with wol activated and i know its MAC , is there a way to check if the computer is plugged in to network?

Tags: lan, wake-on-lan, security-warning

I am thinking of a security system for my small company, i would like to know if there is a way to know even when the computer is turned off when the computer gets disconnected (Knowing the mac an ip)

Imagine this, i have 20 laptops in my office , some may be on , some off, but i know everyones mac an ips , all of then have WOL capabilities activated, what i am thinking is a script that could be sending this kind of ping to the computer lets say every 30 secs to know if they are still connected to the network.

If a computer does not answer in the 30 sec check i would immediately send an automatic email to security office in the building with the information of the machine missing, indicating exact position since i have a previous inventory of the physical location of every address and laptop, thank you in advanced for your responses..

Comment: Alternatively, physical security is a great thing to have

Answer (score 0):

For handling your requirement, it will be better to go for a .net application rather than sticking with a script. .Net has libraries such as System.Net which provides functions for pinging a system by providing its IP. Moreover there are library collections such as System.Net.Mail which provides e-mail facilities.

Comment: If the computer is off, it won't have an IP address...